# MacOS: How to unfreeze terminal after losing connection to remote server

Tags: macos, terminal

Each time I'm connecting to a remote server via SSH and loosing the connection, either I wait for a very long time until getting back the prompt, or I just close the terminal tab and open a new one.

Is it possible to force ending such frozen remote connection ?

Comment: I think this is more suitable on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), another Stack Exchange community that is for general usage of Apple products. See related questions like these: [How to unfreeze terminal when SSH connection dies?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175667/253138), [What can I do when my SSH session is stuck?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35524/253138)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `~.` in the stuck ssh terminal.

Note that it needs to be the first thing on a line so if you’ve already typed something in there, press `enter` first.

Edit: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29942/how-can-i-break-out-of-ssh-when-it-locks) from 11 years ago has more details on the SSH control sequences available.